# Drop down position

Tags: css, menu, position

Having some problems getting the drop down menu position or mainly the background of it in place with the links from drop down menu, can't figure out what could be the problem... Here's the CSS code (menu li ul) image on how it looks -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWMOh.jpg or jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F5wCG/3/

```
.menu ul{
background-color: transparent;
height: 25px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
clear: left;
float: right;
text-align: center;
right: 50%;

}
.menu li{
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    }

.menu li a{ /* Where main link names are etc */
    background: #333 url("images/seperator.gif") bottom right no-repeat;
    color: #CCC;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .menu li a:hover, .menu ul li:hover a{
        background-color: #2580A2;
        background-image: url('images/hover.gif');
        background-position: bottom center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        text-decoration:none;
        }

.menu li ul{ /* Drop down menu */
    background-color: #333;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    border: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 225px;
    z-index: 200;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    }

.menu li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    }

.menu li li {
    background: url('images/sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 220px;
    }

.menu li:hover li a{
    background: none;

    }

.menu li ul a{
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    }

    .menu li ul a:hover, .menu li ul li:hover a{
        background: #2580A2;
        background-image: url(images/hover_sub.gif);
        background-position: center left;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 0px;
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        }

.menu p{
    clear: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/F5wCG/4/

Basically remove 
.menu li { left: 50% }
and add
.menu li a {left:0; }

Comment: It's like this http://i.imgur.com/MrOw3.jpg now, and the center effect goes away (maybe I should have mention that I want the menu centerd)